# How do I specify offset and access in mmap?

Tags: python, mmap

Given mmap's constructor declaration:

`class mmap.mmap(fileno, length[, flags[, prot[, access[, offset]]]])`

**How do I specify both access & offset?**

The documentation states:

> access may be specified in lieu of flags and prot as an optional
>   keyword parameter. It is an error to specify both flags, prot and
>   access. See the description of access above for information on how to
>   use this parameter.

So I've tried to do things like

- `mmap.mmap(file_no, length, offset, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY)`
- `mmap.mmap(file_no, length, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=offset)`

  > > > m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 4, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=2)
  > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):
  > > >         File "", line 1, in 
  > > >       mmap.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
- `mmap.mmap(file_no, length, mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset)`

But I can't get it to work. Why is this confusing me so much?

Comment: The following looks correct: `mmap.mmap(file_no, length, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=offset)`. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Updated question to show you. just an invalid argument error (and yes, it works if I take away the offset=2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is unrelated to access. As  [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap), the offset just must be a multiple of `mmap.PAGESIZE` or `mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY`.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I confused myself when `m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 4, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE, 2)` *seemed* to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 4, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=2 * mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY)
```